# Multi-headed Gaming VM Host on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, xen

I am trying to build a multi-headed gaming system based on an Ubuntu Server 15.04 host with either Windows or Ubuntu/Linux Mint guests.  I have gotten the systems nearly working with Linux Mint/Ubuntu Hosts but have issues where the guest VMs (Windows 8.1 or Win10TechPreview) lose the GPU passthrough between reboots (Xen hypervisor, apparently due to xl framework/Windows 8+ issues?) and where I cannot pass through my usb2 or usb3 expansion cards (KVM hypervisor, due to IOMMU groups).  I am in the process of installing Ubuntu Server but I am stuck at the software packages options and wondering: What does choosing the VM host option during installation actually do?

Comment: Are you trying to run graphic intensive games on a virtual machine?

Comment: Nothing terribly demanding.  I had Left4Dead 2 and Lego Batman 2/3 running alright on my previous attempts.